Why is PWA Not Consistently Updating Devices With Code Changes?
I am working with PWA and finding updating of code changes to be extremely inconsistent in its behaviour.
I understand that following any code changes (javascript or html etc) then within the sw.js file you change the version number.
I have tried different sw.js files including Google's example and examples from online courses.
None of these work consistently.
The PWA is being delivered via IIS.
To test this am I adding a simple alert to one of the js files, then altering the version in the sw.js file.
After much head scratching I thought maybe the fault was within IIS so I turned off cacheing there. I thought this was the solution as my iPhone 15 started working perfectly. Today tried other devices to find it didn't
Here are my results earlier today
iPhone 15 works perfectly.
Android phone not working
iPad not working.
In IIS did a restart of the site and the App Pool.
Suddenly everything seems to be working .... for now .... more than likely one device will stop working at some point as that is my experience in the past.
In the past I have reset IIS to find it did 'not' solve the problem.
Everything seems rather shakey.
Does anyone have any advice? Is it IIS at fault? Any other setting changes needed?

Updating code changes in a PWA can indeed be tricky due to the way service workers cache assets. The behavior you're experiencing is likely due to caching inconsistencies across different devices and browsers. you can try to clear browser cache and configure IIS for no caching.
